# How to use ddblock to create slideshow?

Tags: views, 7, javascript

I am having problem creating slideshow with DDBlock

Created a new block 'DDBlock1' from 'admin/structure/ddblock'
    Cannot configure Block: Selected "Input Type" as "Content Type" but under "Content Type" drop down box, only option is "None" (as shown)

[image]

I am stuck here - how do I direct DDBlock to pick images from an Image field in a content type I have??

Comment: which tutorial did you follow

Comment: If you are no longer having problem then its okay. Otherwise you can see this page http://drupal.org/node/418616, it lists many slideshow modules, you can choose from there

Comment: Summarized the question to a specific issue only (to get started) - Appreciate any help

Comment: @user1406716 Are you aware that the community expects you to pick an answer for your questions? I tend to ignore questions asked by people with a red accept rating like yourself, as I feel it signals "Help vampire". It would be appreciated if you went over your older questions and did some clean up :)

Comment: @Letharion - Thanks for pointing that out - I was actually not aware. I have gone through my questions and marked the answers that resolved my issues. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you noticed that the help text says

> Only content types enabled in the settings tab of the ddblock module will show up here

?

As far as I can tell from your question, you haven't enabled your content type, and thus that's likely your problem.

Comment: Where exactly is the 'settings' tab? I have created a new block from '/admin/structure/ddblock' and while configuring the DDBlock1 created, I did select the content type but it did not ask me which fields. 

I think I am not able to find the right settings form for ddblock?

Comment: From looking at `hook_menu` in the module, I'm guessing the settings tab is `admin/structure/ddblock/settings`, but I'm not at all familiar with the module, so I can't really say.

Comment: THank you - that helped. Now I cannot see the DDBlock at all - but that was not part of this question - thank you.